# How to disable task if process already ran today

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm trying to automate and streamline a daily process that I've been babysitting for several months. Because our upstream pipeline can and may be delayed for several hours, I've created a package that checks the pipeline every 30 minutes. Once the pipeline completes, I manually perform steps 2 - 6.

I have stored procedures that will execute steps 3 - 6, but each step can only run once per day and only after step 2 completes.

Step 6 only after step 5.

In the attached image.
Can someone show me how to disable a task based on step 1 value?

[image: process flow]

Comment: Use Container to add a condition and Stop the execution. If you can add the SPs and table schema and data scripts with the requirement, I can send you a sample. @SJJ9166